# Reassigning the whole tuple works

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

I am learning the data structure of Tuple in Python, and I read that Tuple is immutable: this means that we cannot set its element using the assignment operator ("="), but I wonder why can I set the whole tuple using the assignment operator, like:

```
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> t = (3,4,5)
>>> print(t) 
(3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Because you're not mutating the tuple, but you're assigning a new one?

Comment: If I've got a magic impervious rock I can't change in any way, that doesn't stop me from putting it down and picking up a different rock.

Comment: You're creating a new tuple, and changing the variable to refer to that instead.

Comment: You're just moving a label, not mutating any tuple. Recommended reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Comment: Assignment doesn't mutate any object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But how about when we use assignment operator to set individual element in a specific index? (use the same example) like: t[0] = 3. I am trying to mutate the element with assignment operator, which python will not allow me to.

Comment: @JoySun that's different.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying tuple means that you want to mess with its inner belongings. Tuple is an object in Python, and all objects are represented in code as pointers. A pointer can be reassigned to represent **any** object, hence dynamic typing in Python.

```
t = (1,2,3)
# this is valid
t = []
# and this too
t = "string"
```

`t` is a pointer to your tuple, which can be modified, but not its elements.
Consider this:

```
# create tuple
t = (1,2,3)

# access its first element
print(t[0])

# try to modify first element 
t[0] = 5
```

Output:

```
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/zzz/scratch.py", line 5, in <module>
    t[0] = 5
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Remembering the concept that every variable in python is a pointer is a good idea. Cause this can also explain why codes like (a, b) = (b, a+b) works (which was my original question): it is because (a, b) is a pointer, that is, it stores some tuple's address, assigning a new address of another tuple to it works just fine. Is that right?

Comment: Well, if you store `(a,b)` in some variable, you can do that. The statement `(a, b) = (b, a+b)` as it is wont work, because `(a,b)` is an object literal, a statement, rather than a variable. You can only assign values to variables.

Comment: example of what you mention (if I understand correctly) `t = (1,2,3)` and then `t = (t[1],t[2]+1,t[0])`

Comment: `(a, b) = (b, a+b)` works fine: it's an unpacking. Conventionally this would be written without parentheses, but it's not wrong to include them.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're assigning the tuple to a new variable. You're not changing the values.
But instead you're creating new one's.

Let me explain:
Once we've declared the contents of a tuple, we can't modify the contents inside that tuple.
That doesn't mean we can't assign it to a different variable.

For example, here's how we modify the 0th member of a list:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> mylist[0] = 69
print(mylist)
[69, 2, 3]
```

That will not work with a tuple:

```
>>> mytuple = (1, 2, 3)
>>> mytuple[0] = 69
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I hope you got the answer. Because assigning to a variable is a whole different thing than mutating.

Answer (score 0):

Think about reference vs. value in your examples. You are reassigning the variable from one tuple to another, not modifying the data.

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
s = (3, 4, 5)
u = (3, 4, 5) 

t = s    # t = (3, 4, 5)
print(t) #     (3, 4, 5)

print(t == s) # True, same values
print(t is s) # True, they point to the same address in memory
print(t == u) # True, same values
print(t is u) # False, they point to different addresses(think physical locations) in memory.
```

In Python you are able to reassign variables, and if you're coming from other languages, you may be used to having more restrictions. Python is more loose in this sense.

For Python tuples, immutability means that you can't change primitive values, think of them as read-only:

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
t[0] += 1    # TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
t.append(4)  # AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: I run the code and got print(t is u) as True, which makes sense since u and s point to the same address, s and t point to the same address , so that t and s should point to the same address.

Answer (score -1):

t = (1,2,3)

t = (5,3,9) is not an edit in the old tuple. The data held by previous t variable is reassigned to a new variable, which name is also t.

the important point is that t is just a name for the tuple we might call t. In particular, you can make t a name for something else by rebinding it, say t = 2. But you can't change the element inside the tuple!

The immutability of an object means, that once the object has been created in a memory, it can only be destroyed

that's just how variable assignment works in Python. Variables are just names, assignment to a variable means you are asking the computer to compute the expression on the right hand side, and store its value into the name on the left hand side.

Comment: It's not clear why you're bringing up `t = t`. The question doesn't include a `t = t` line.

Comment: it is the same to assign new value or to assign the old one the same but yah i edit it